# how to mute a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, mute

I load a movieclip in another project. this loop.swf has music in it.

```
loopingLoader = new Loader;
loopingLoader.load(new URLRequest("img/loop.swf"));
addChild(loopingLoader);
```

After some seconds, I want to unload or easier "mute" this clip.

When I unload it, even when I load a new clip in it, the music continues to play.

How can I mute this clip?

Thanks for your help.

N

Answer (score 0):

you can control global sounds or stop all sounds in flash player via the *SoundMixer* class by setting the *soundTransform* property or calling the *stopAll()* function respectively:

[flash.media.SoundMixer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html)

Comment: the problem is, i only wanna stop one movieclip sound, i have another movieclip who should continue to play.

Comment: I try to dispose it like this: removeChild(loopingLoader); loopingLoader.unload(); System.gc();

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing and disposing you clip correctly?

This helps if you just wants to mute all sounds:

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform.volume = 0
```

Comment: I try to dispose it like this: removeChild(loopingLoader);
   loopingLoader.unload();
   System.gc();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
loopingLoader.unloadAndStop();
```